# How to serve mp4 from bluemix application

Tags: ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty

I have a bluemix J2EE application that uses several mp4 video clips. The video's are present on the server, but they fail to load. The mp4 player shows "loading" but never displays the video. They are working properly from a locally deployed Tomcat instance, just not from the Bluemix deployment. I suspect there is a supported content type configuration somewhere that needs to be updated to include .mp4 but I'm not sure where that would be. Any help appreciated.

Comment: does it work if it's really small?

Comment: I have a total of 6 files, ranging in size from 76k to 732k - none of them are served.

Comment: Does the client send a Range: request? When you request the file directly, does it show up with an appropriate Content-Type?

Comment: It appears to work correctly from Firefox and Chrome, but not Safari.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly encourage not to host any large files inside of your app in Bluemix.  I would highly encourage you to look at a CDN or an object storage service such as the one in Bluemix or Openstack Swift.  The reasoning behind this is that there is a file size limit on your application.  The limit is on log files, the middleware (the runtime, node or java or etc), and the app code itself.  Having large files in your app fills this limit up quicker.  Currently the limit is 1GB and this is Cloud Foundry imposed.

Comment: These are a total of 6 mp4's that are part of the documentation. I have packaged them separately for custom deployments but need them to work in the reference implementation (on Bluemix). The video's do take up a good bit of space, but the application has a very small footprint otherwise and is well within the 1Gb limit. Is there any way to serve this content without looking to add another service to this application?

Comment: It should work, are you setting the headers for the content type?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, the mp4 files are statically served as a component of a static web page which is served up from the web content folder of the J2EE application. This is not dynamic content, just documentation. See the "overview" video [here](http://idmu.mybluemix.net)  for details

Answer (score 1):

I just hacked up a very simple WAR to test this out. Things are working fine for me (both local Liberty deployment and Bluemix deployment). I am not sure how you have your things configured, but here's my source:

WebContent/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
Basic HTML file
<p><a href="basicServlet">Basic Servlet</a></p>
<p><a href="basic.mp4">Basic MP4</a></p>
<p><a href="basic.mp3">Basic MP3</a></p>
<p><a href="basic.jpeg">Basic JPEG</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

The basicServlet, mp4, mp3 and jpeg are all peer files in WebContent.

The basicServlet is annotated (no web.xml):

```
package net.wasdev.sample;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/basicServlet")
public class SimpleServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.getWriter().append("Basic Servlet at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    }
}
```

Are you able to access these files directly? I am able to access them directly in both local Liberty and Bluemix. I am not using any embedded video because if the file can be served up then the rest is just the embedded video player.

Comment: So these are just static video clips, embedded in documentation (static web pages). And the embedded video appears to work correctly in Chrome and Firefox, but not Safari. Here are some details.
In the userguide.html document I have the following markup
`<video width="50%" controls style="float:right;padding:15px;">
          <source src="video/Cut3.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      </video>` and Cut3.mp4 exists in `..defaultServer/apps/idmu/video`

Answer (score 0):

Check the mp4 files path, and the content type returned on the header when requesting the mp4 files. If wrong set it when returning the files. 
I suggest you to use html5 video tag setting the content correctly.
If it is indefinitely loading I suspect that the mp4 file path is wrong. 
If you wish, paste your site URL, we could check what could be wrong